# A problem from Gallian's Algebraic Extensions

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let $a$ be a complex number that is algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$ and let $p(x)$ denote the minimal polynomial of $a$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. Show that $\sqrt{a}$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$ and determine the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt{a}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. Does your argument work when $\sqrt{a}$ is replaced by $\sqrt[n]{a}$ ?

---

This is a problem for Gallian's "[*Contemporary abstract algebra*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1133599702)", chapter "Algebraic Extensions" on which I'm completely stuck. Can someone help me please.

Comment: To you get you started, imagine you have the minimal polynomial $p(x) = c_kx^k + c_{k-1}x^{k - 1} + \ldots + c_0$ for $a$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. How can you modify this polynomial such that $\sqrt{a}$ is a root of it?

Comment: could not get it. will you please explain please.and what about the second part.

Comment: Try some examples.  For example, $a = \sqrt{2}$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$ and its minimal polynomial is $p(x) = x^2 - 2$.  What is the minimal polynomial for $\sqrt{a}$ in this example?

Comment: As ferson, and DonAntonio indicate finding a polynomial with rational coefficients that has $\sqrt a$ is not difficult. The question about minimal polynomial is a different matter. For example starting with the minimal polynomial of $a=3+2\sqrt2$, and carrying out the hinted process won't give you the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt a$. The reason: $a=(1+\sqrt)^2$, so the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt a$ is quadratic, where as the natural process leads to a quartic.

Comment: To find the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt{a}$, a starting point is that if you have a non-trivial factorization, $p(x^2) = q_1(x) q_2(x)$, apply the symmetry $x \mapsto -x$ to conclude that either $q_1(x) = q_1(-x)$ and $q_2(x) = q_2(-x)$ (this case is quickly eliminated because $p(x)$ is irreducible) or $q_1(x) = q_2(-x)$ and $q_2(x) = q_1(-x)$.  Thus, if $p(x^2)$ factors, it factors in the form $p(x^2) = q(x) q(-x)$ for some polynomial $q(x)$ of degree $\deg(p(x))$.

Answer (score 3):

Following Ferson's comment + hint:

$$\sum_{n=0}^kc_na^n=0\implies \sum_{n=0}^k c_n(\sqrt a)^{2n}=0\ldots$$

Comment: similarly then second part also is trye.am I right?

Comment: Yup, indeed so...